# How to get array element one by one in js

Tags: javascript, html, web-deployment

I want to change **image** and **text** by clicking the button using the array
but the entire array shows when clicking the button

How do I create a loop for this? so that the array element shows one by one.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    img: "https://www.tourmyindia.com/blog//wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Best-Places-to-Visit-in-Bhopal-MP-Sanchi-Stupa.jpg",
    place: "BHOPAL",
    state: "MADHYA PRADESH",
  },
  {
    img: "https://www.tourmyindia.com/blog//wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Best-Places-to-Visit-in-Bhopal-MP-Sanchi-Stupa.jpg",
    place: "MUMBAI",
    state: "MAHARASHTRA",
  },
];

function show(){
let cluster = "";
arr.forEach((item) => {
    cluster =
      cluster +
      ` <h1>${item.place}</h1>
                <div class="vt-bar"></div>
                <h3>${item.state}</h3>
                <div class="arrow">
                    <i class="ri-arrow-left-line"></i>
                    <div class="hz-bar"></div>
                    <i class="ri-arrow-right-line"></i>
                </div>`;
  });
document.getElementById("cluster").innerHTML = cluster;
};

document.getElementById("random").addEventListener("click", function(){
  show();
});
```

Comment: use a map function for an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using foreach loop use index value to get data. Your code should be

```
var counter = 0;
const arr = [
  {
    img: "https://www.tourmyindia.com/blog//wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Best-Places-to-Visit-in-Bhopal-MP-Sanchi-Stupa.jpg",
    place: "BHOPAL",
    state: "MADHYA PRADESH",
  },
  {
    img: "https://www.tourmyindia.com/blog//wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Best-Places-to-Visit-in-Bhopal-MP-Sanchi-Stupa.jpg",
    place: "MUMBAI",
    state: "MAHARASHTRA",
  },
];

function show(){
    let cluster = "";
    if (counter<arr.length){
        cluster =
          cluster +
          ` <h1>${arr[counter].place}</h1>
                    <div class="vt-bar"></div>
                    <h3>${arr[counter].state}</h3>
                    <div class="arrow">
                        <i class="ri-arrow-left-line"></i>
                        <div class="hz-bar"></div>
                        <i class="ri-arrow-right-line"></i>
                    </div>`;
        document.getElementById("cluster").innerHTML = cluster;
        counter++;
    }
    
}

document.getElementById("random").addEventListener("click", function(){
  show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no need to loop through the array. You just need to maintain a counter here.

```
const arr = [
  {
    img: "https://www.tourmyindia.com/blog//wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Best-Places-to-Visit-in-Bhopal-MP-Sanchi-Stupa.jpg",
    place: "BHOPAL",
    state: "MADHYA PRADESH",
  },
  {
    img: "https://www.tourmyindia.com/blog//wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Best-Places-to-Visit-in-Bhopal-MP-Sanchi-Stupa.jpg",
    place: "MUMBAI",
    state: "MAHARASHTRA",
  },
];

function show(index){
    
    let cluster =  ` <h1>${arr[counter].place}</h1>
                    <div class="vt-bar"></div>
                    <h3>${arr[counter].state}</h3>
                    <div class="arrow">
                        <i class="ri-arrow-left-line"></i>
                        <div class="hz-bar"></div>
                        <i class="ri-arrow-right-line"></i>
                    </div>`;

    
document.getElementById("cluster").innerHTML = cluster;
};

var counter = 0;

document.getElementById("random").addEventListener("click", function(){

  show(counter);
    if(counter<arr.length-1){
    counter++;
    }
    else{
    counter = 0;
    }
});
```

please don't use cluster+ as it will concatenate the previous data too.

Answer (score 0):

what i understand please try this

```js
const arr = [{
    img: "https://www.tourmyindia.com/blog//wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Best-Places-to-Visit-in-Bhopal-MP-Sanchi-Stupa.jpg",
    place: "BHOPAL",
    state: "MADHYA PRADESH",
  },
  {
    img: "https://www.tourmyindia.com/blog//wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Best-Places-to-Visit-in-Bhopal-MP-Sanchi-Stupa.jpg",
    place: "MUMBAI",
    state: "MAHARASHTRA",
  },
  {
    img: "https://www.tourmyindia.com/blog//wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Best-Places-to-Visit-in-Bhopal-MP-Sanchi-Stupa.jpg",
    place: "Bur",
    state: "Dubai",
  },
  {
    img: "https://www.tourmyindia.com/blog//wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Best-Places-to-Visit-in-Bhopal-MP-Sanchi-Stupa.jpg",
    place: "Chinnai",
    state: "MAHARASHTRA",
  }
];

let cluster = "";
let i = 0;

function show() {
  if (i === arr.length) return;
  item = arr[i];
  let clusterElem = document.getElementById("cluster");
  if (i === 0) {
    cluster = cluster +
      ` <div class="row"><h1>${item.place}</h1>
                <div class="vt-bar"></div>
                <h3>${item.state}</h3>
                <div class="arrow">
                    <i class="ri-arrow-left-line"></i>
                    <div class="hz-bar"></div>
                    <i class="ri-arrow-right-line"></i>
                </div></div>`;
    clusterElem.innerHTML = cluster;
  } else {
    cluster = cluster +
      `<div class="row"><h1>${item.place}</h1>
                <div class="vt-bar"></div>
                <h3>${item.state}</h3>
                <div class="arrow">
                    <i class="ri-arrow-left-line"></i>
                    <div class="hz-bar"></div>
                    <i class="ri-arrow-right-line"></i>
                </div></div>`;
    clusterElem.innerHTML = cluster;
  }
  i++;
};

document.getElementById("random").addEventListener("click", function() {
  show();
});
```

```html
<div id="cluster"></div>
<button id="random"> Click</button>
```